# Cannot convert to System.Byte

Tags: javascript, base64

I am using trying to send an ajax post request with some text & files. However the accepted file format is base64binary (it is specified by the api to accept the post request)

Am using the below javascript function to convert the image file to a base64:

```js
function encodeImageFileAsURL(){

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("image").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0)
    {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

            var newImage = document.createElement('img');
            newImage.src = srcData;

            convertedimage = srcData;
            
            document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
            //alert("Converted Base64 version is "+document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
            console.log("Converted Base64 version is "+document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```

And using a simple ajax call to send the data.

This is the response I am getting from the api:
Cannot convert data:image/png;base64,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... to System.Byte.
Parameter name: type ---> Input string was not in a correct format.

Would anyone tell me about the way or approach to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should remove the header "data:image/png;base64," and only send "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...."

Comment: Thank you syllabus. I actually did tried that but it didn't work..   I have use this line to eliminate the header   var data = srcData.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,'');   I got exactly the same error.

Comment: if you got EXACTLY the same error "Cannot convert data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...", I guess that your substitution is not at the right place because the header is still there. Actually I don't have any other idea, the data is in base64. May be check the server with a static string. good luck